# javascript recursion first char of string1 then last char of string2

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have two strings, n1 = abc and n2 = xyz. How can I print "azbycx" recursively?

Here is my code. I am practicing string manipulations and I can't seem to find a solution to this. I Googled already and can't seem to find one.

```
document.write(practice("abc","xyz"));

function practice(n1,n2){

if(n1.length==0){return n2;}
if(n2.length==0){return n1;}

return n1.substring(0,1) + practice(n2.charAt(n2.length-1),n1.substring(1));
}
```

It prints only "azc" :(

Comment: Why do you feel that recursion is the way to go?

Comment: true... a simple for loop with i (forward) for n1 and n-i-1 (reversed) for n2 would suffice.

Comment: i am not so sure really. that cant be solved by recursion?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem.

Comment: recursion has it's own set of problems - complexity, performance, risk of going into infinite recursion etc... so if there is a simpler way avoid recursion.

Comment: why most here treat as homework? lol. i graduated last 2006 and now i am practicing java and javascript. i am practicing my thinking skills. i am not student.

Comment: @gp. so when i have a solution i go first for iterative and not recursion? cos i am applying for programmer trainee job and i had my exams like that. recursion is my last resort of solution?

Comment: yes... infact, if you check in browsers, there are actually limits on how many recursive calls you could have which varies depending on the number of function parameters.

Comment: ok thank u. i appreciate. i wish i was a student again. hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function practice(n1,n2){
    console.log(n1);
    console.log(n2);
    if(n1.length==0){return n2;}
    if(n2.length==0){return n1;}


    return n1[0]+n2[n2.length-1] + practice(n1.substring(1), n2.substring(0, n2.length-1));
}
```

Comment: n1[0] is possible? what it does?

Comment: It is possible, it is similar to `charAt()` function. In this string treated as an array like object, where individual characters are correspond to a numerical index (ex: "str"[0] returns "s").

Comment: another question: what about console.log(n1) and console.log(n2)? do i need to put that always? i dont know what that does.

Comment: The `console` object provides access to the browser's debugging console. `console.log()` prints given value to the web console

Answer (score 0):

```
function practice(n1,n2){

    if(n1.length==0){return n2;}
    if(n2.length==0){return n1;}

    if (n2.length > n1.length) {
        return n2.charAt(n2.length-1) + practice(n1, n2.substring(0, n2.length-1));
    }
    else {
        return n1.charAt(0) + practice(n1.substring(1), n2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var practice = function(n1,n2) {
    var _charA = n1.charAt(0)
    var _charB = n2.charAt(n2.length-1)

    var _res = "";
    if(_charA != "" || _charB != "") {
        _res = practice(n1.substring(1,[n1.length]),n2.substring(0,[n2.length-1]))
    }
    return _charA + _charB + _res;
}

practice("abcd", "uvwxyz")
//output - azbycxdwvu
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you like it to do:

```
function practice(n1,n2){
  if(n1.length==0 && n2.length==0)
    return "";

  return n1.substr(0,1) + n2.substr(n2.length-1, 1) + 
         practice(n1.substr(1, n1.length-1), n2.substr(0, n2.length-1));
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gt7fsb7g/

Comment: I want to point out that Randy B.'s original code for handling the termination condition won't handle n1 and n2 of different lengths very well. For example, if practice is called with ("abc", "tuvwxyz"), the original code would yield something like "azbycxtuvw" instead of "azbycxwvut".